# How to create connection pool for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, connection, pool

I'm new to Cassandra and trying to create a connection pool. As readying through the documentation, I see that in previous version, PoolingOptions was how it was done. But the new documentation, version 4.1 has nothing about pooling options on the connection pool section. So is there a new way to do the connection pool without using PoolingOptions?

Answer (score 0):

This is now done via configuration options, like this (look for [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.1/manual/core/pooling/)):

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection {
  max-requests-per-connection = 1024
  pool {
    local.size = 1
    remote.size = 1
  }
}
```

New driver uses another way to configure everything, please refer to [getting started guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.1/manual/core/#setting-up-the-driver) & [upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.1/upgrade_guide/) on how to switch to new configuration.